# how to read data into object array in Swift 4

Tags: swift, class

```
class Employee{
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var salary:Int

    init(){
        self.id=0
        self.name=""
        self.salary=0
    }

    func getInfo(){
        self.name=readLine()!
        self.id=Int(readLine()!)!
        self.salary=Int(readLine()!)!
    }
}


var count=0
var flag="y"
var empData:[Employee]=[]
repeat{
    count+=1
    empData[count]=Employee()
    empData[count].getInfo()
    flag=readLine()!

}while(flag=="y") `
```

I have a class `Employee` with properties `id` , `nam` and `salary`. The function `getInfo()` is used to get information from user. I want to read data until the `flag!="y"` . I am getting index out of range error.

> What is the right way of inputting data? Can we index the objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append to your array to make it increase in size. Replace

```
empData[count]=Employee()
```

with

```
empData.append(Employee())
```

to avoid index out of range error

*Update*

To make your code a little less horrible I would do

```
repeat {
    var employee = Employee()
    employee.getInfo()
    empData.append(employee)
    flag=readLine()!
}while( flag == "y" )
```

Answer (score 1):

The subscript operator cannot be used to add elements to an array index which doesn't exist yet. You either need to initialize the array with an element count if you know at the time of initialization how many elements your array will have or use the `append` operator to add new elements to the array after the last index.

You don't even need the `count` variable, as you can simply access `empData.last` safely after calling `append` and adding a new `Employee` to the `Array`.

```
var flag="y"
var empData:[Employee]=[]
repeat {
    empData.append(Employee())
    empData.last!.getInfo()
    flag=readLine()!
} while(flag=="y")
```

I would advise you to seriously reconsider your implementation as it is really unsafe at the moment. You are not validating user input in any way, hence your `getInfo` function can easily cause runtime errors if the user input is not in the expected form. Moreover, creating an empty initializer for `Employee` doesn't make sense, you could simply create a failable initializer, where you read the input and if the input is not of the correct form, make the initializer return `nil`.

```
class Employee{
    let id:Int
    let name:String
    let salary:Int

    init?(){
        guard let name = readLine() else { return nil }
        self.name = name
        guard let idString = readLine(), let id = Int(idString) else { return nil }
        self.id = id
        guard let salaryString = readLine(), let salary = Int(salaryString) else { return nil}
        self.salary = salary
    }
}

var flag="y"
var empData:[Employee]=[]
repeat {
    if let employee = Employee() {
        empData.append(employee)
    } else {
        // Display error message to the user
    }
    flag=readLine() ?? ""
} while(flag=="y")
```